# no main manifest attribute error after add volley.jar library

Tags: android, intellij-idea, jar, android-volley

i could not build my project because of "no main manifest attribute" error

1)i copied volley.jar in libs folder

2)right clicked volley, clicked "add as library" then choosed "project library"

3)add <'application
            android:name="com.example.docar.app.AppController".../>' to AndroidManifest.xml

still got problem.

screen shot
[image: screen shot]

Comment: Did you try utilizing the gradle dependency - `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'`? It isn't an official version, but they update it weekly. May help avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem in this case appears to be the "Run configuration" which is set to run a library instead of the Android Application that should be run.

This can be solved by the following steps here to create/edit the configuration for your "Android Application": http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Simple_Android_application_from_scratch_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_11.0#Running_Android_Application

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a direct answer to your problem, but since you appear to be using Android Studio... there is an unofficial (not maintained by Google) Gradle mirror for the Volley library maintained here:
https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

You can add this to your build.gradle by including this compile line:

`compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'`

Comment: i am using IntelliJ IDEA, added new named volley. in volley folder i open build.gradle change its content to
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
}
still have problem

Comment: @MuratVAROL Can you post a screenshot of the build.gradle file so that we can inspect what might be wrong?
Also, have you reverted the previous change to AndroidManifest.xml?  The AppController line shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @MuratVAROL Now I see the problem. The "build.gradle" that you are modifying, is of the project "Volley" but your Android project is "docar" and is ant-based(there is a build.xml, but no pom.xml, and no build.gradle)

Please revert your change to the "build.gradle". The problem is not there. The problem is with your Run configuration. In the top-right corner of your screen, where you see "android-support-v4.jar" with a green triangle next to it, click that, and go to "Edit configurations" and check if you have an "Android Application" configuration.

Comment: sorry i am new on android, so what should i do

Comment: @MuratVAROL No worries. Try going to the menu "Run> Edit Configurations" as shown in this image:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/images/java-unit-testing/running-tests-from-idea-1.png

You should see a run configuration called "Android Application". If not, follow the steps here to add one:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-an-android-run-debug-configuration.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66161/discussion-between-yaraju-and-murat-varol).

Answer (score 0):

just open `build.gradle` of your app and this line to your dependencies.

```
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for try to help,

changed library settings [right click library->open library setting] and change setting to as below image

program crushed after run :) but i can build it now.[image: solution]